# How do I send cmd key mappings on macOS from kitty to neovim?

Tags: neovim, kitty

I'd like to use the following mapping in my `mappings.lua` configuration:

```lua
map('n', '<C-D-[>', ':BufferPrevious<cr>', options)
map('n', '<C-D-]>', ':BufferNext<cr>', options)
map('n', '<C-D-w>', ':BufferClose<cr>', options)
```

I currently have this in my `kitty.conf` which is not working.

```
map ctrl+cmd+[ send_text all ?
```

Comment: [It might not be possible](https://superuser.com/questions/387897/can-i-use-the-cmd-key-in-terminal-vim-at-all)

Answer (score -2):

The latest commit of the current Neovide repository does not support macOS without Python2 installed.

To fix this, you should revert to commit `db53e94` after cloning the repository. To do this, execute the following command:

```
git reset --hard db53e94
```

And add the following environment variables in `zshrc`:

```
export SKIA_BINARIES_URL=https://github.91chi.fun//https://github.com/rust-skia/skia-binaries/releases/download/{tag}/skia-binaries-{key}.tar.gz
```

Restart the shell, re-use the `cargo bundle --release` command to build the App, and drag the built App to the /Applications folder.